# Get cell value from dataGridView when dataGridView.Columns.Insert is in code

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have `DataTable table` in `DataGridView dataGridView1` with several text and integer columns. They are added with:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

table.Columns.Add("Guest name", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Guest_id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Room_id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Room", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Reservation_id", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Reservation date", typeof(DateTime));
table.Columns.Add("Start date", typeof(DateTime));
table.Columns.Add("End date", typeof(DateTime));

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Then added buttons to `dataGridView1` to specific columns:

```
DataGridViewButtonColumn editGuest = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
DataGridViewButtonColumn editRoom = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
DataGridViewButtonColumn editReservation = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
DataGridViewButtonColumn deleteReservation = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();

editGuest.Name = "Edit guest";
editGuest.Text = "Edit";
editGuest.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
editRoom.Name = "Edit room";
editRoom.Text = "Edit";
editRoom.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
editReservation.Name = "Edit reservation";
editReservation.Text = "Edit";
editReservation.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
deleteReservation.Name = "Delete reservation";
deleteReservation.Text = "Delete";
deleteReservation.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, editGuest);
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(5, editRoom);
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(10, editReservation);
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(11, deleteReservation);
```

All data are insert into `table` from database and it's looking good. Now I tryed to click on (any) button and get text from (any) cell. Tryed:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            string text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Always get "Edit" or "Delete" message no matter which number is in Cell[]. It seems that `dataGridView1` have only buttons inside and not table. How to get value from `table` cell and not `dataGridView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my quick test shows that there are values in cells, maybe you need to select a different index.

to get only data items (excluding unbound columns), try use `DataBoundItem` property of DataGridViewRow. when binding to DataTable is used, the real type will be DataRowView.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn)
    {
        var cellValues = Enumerable.Range(0, senderGrid.Columns.Count)
                                   .Select(i => senderGrid[i, e.RowIndex].Value);
        string text = String.Join("; ", cellValues);
        MessageBox.Show(text);

        var rw = senderGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
        text = String.Join("; ", rw.Row.ItemArray);
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: You sir, saved me! DataRowView (2nd var paragraph in if statement) is what I was looking.